# My code was 2nd. I needed it as short as possible

Tags: javascript, string

The goal was to create a phone number from a given string(S), which was random. the format of the number had to be (XXX) XXX-XXXX. Can the code be made even shorter?

```
S=readline()
        let X="("+S[0]+S[1]+S[2]+")"+
        " "+S[3]+S[4]+S[5]+"-"+S[6]+S[7]+S[8]+S[9]
    print(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regex](https://regex101.com/):

```
let X = S.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3")
```